# SQL Query for Count of distinct values in a column for every distinct value in other column

Tags: sql

Scenario:

I had a datatable containing names of different companies. For each distinct company from that table, I would like to calculate number of locations its existing.

Sample data:

```
Cmpny.COMPANY ID | Cmpny.OFFICELOCATION

1      |       1
1      |       1
1      |       2
1      |       3    
2      |       1
2      |       4
2      |       4
2      |       2
```

Result Required:

```
COMPANY ID | OFFICELOCATION | Count(OfficeLocation)

    1      |       1        |       2
    1      |       2        |       1
    1      |       3        |       1
    2      |       1        |       1
    2      |       2        |       1    
    2      |       4        |       2
```

ALL

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Hi Gordon, 
Thanks for your hint.
I tried Group by, I am able to get Count of OfficeLocation for each OfficeLocation but I am unable to get seperately for each company ID

Comment: Thanks Tim, 
I tried the following SQL to get count of distinct Office Locations

SELECT distinct OfficeLocation, COUNT(OfficeLocation) FROM dbo.Company GROUP BY OfficeLocation       and am having the following query to get distinct office locations for each company   -  SELECT DISTINCT  CompanyID, OfficeLocation FROM dbo.Company.  But am unable to collate the details of these queries in to one table

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.
So here aggregate function Count(CompanyOfficeLocation) which count depends on CompanyID then Office Location.

The following SQL statement count the Office Location by CompanyID

```
select CompanyID,CompanyOfficeLocation,
count(CompanyOfficeLocation) [Count(OfficeLocation)]
FROM [dbo].[Compny]
group by CompanyID,CompanyOfficeLocation
order by CompanyID,CompanyOfficeLocation
```

Comment: Thanks Nazmul, It helped me!! :)

Comment: Please read the basic of SQL.There are many sites where you can learn SQL Basics.